# Improving many case switch statement

Tags: php

I'm studying some code examples that I haven't written myself, and I found this function which looks to me like it's badly written, or at least not very efficient. Can you suggest ways to improve it? I was thinking this might work with an associative array, but not sure how.

Any other ways this can be re-written?

```
    $op = '';
    switch($style) {
        case 'f':
        case 'F': {
            $op = 'f';
            break;
        }
        case 'f*':
        case 'F*': {
            $op = 'f*';
            break;
        }
        case 'B':
        case 'FD':
        case 'DF': {
            $op = 'B';
            break;
        }
        default: {
            if (!empty($default)) {
                $op = $this->dosomething($default, '');
            } else {
                $op = '';
            }
        }
    }
    return $op;
```

Comment: What on earth is it trying to do?

Comment: It look, fine to me. Concise and efficient, easy to read. What else do you need.

Comment: @BoltClock I have no idea. It's just from a library, some open source code that I thought might help me learn good programming syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an assoc array you would need to do the following:

```
$styles = array(
    'S' => 'S',
    'D' => 'S',
    's' => 's',
    'd' => 's',
    ... etc ...
);

if (isset($styles[$op])) {
    return $styles[$op];
} elseif (!empty($default)) {
    return $this->getPathPaintOperator($default, '');
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to add additional curly braces, you can change

```
 case 'df': {
        $op = 'b';
        break;
    }
```

to

```
 case 'df':
        $op = 'b';
        break;
```

Comment: @switch it was joke. Try to use Petah's answer.

Comment: If your going to be that pedantic, why not just `case 'df': return 'b';`

Comment: @Petah actually that's a pretty good idea too since the whole function is just the switch, so a return should work just fine